# Тип данных Comparable

Tags: java

Наткнулся на одной сайте, что при сортировке используют массив Comparable? Что это за тип данных? Я единственное , что понял, что в Comparable можно как цифры, так и строки подавать. Хотелось бы поподробнее.

Answer (score 1):

`Comparable` — интерфейс.

Объекты класса, реализующего этот интерфейс, умеют сравниваться между собой.
Например: (одна из первых ссылок в гугле)
http://www.javaportal.ru/java/articles/sort.html

Comment: Интерфейс вполне себе тип данных - здесь нет противоречия